# Trouble with appropriately destroying views in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a view that I create twice on two separate tabs. Within each instance of this view I have a bunch of subviews. Each time I create the parent view, it creates new subviews within itself. At the same time, it pushes these subviews to an array that gets called like:

```
    var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        itemViews: [],

        initialize: function(options) {
            var self = this;

            // following creates the specific collection of data
            // is this what I should be using to destroy the subviews
            // rather than the itemViews array?
            this.collection = options.collection;
            this.collection.on('add', self._createSubView, self);

        render: function(){// render stuff},

        _createSubView: function() {
             view = new SubView();
             this.itemViews.push(view);
        },
    });
```

The problem is that sometimes within one of the parent views, I need to destroy its subviews. That's done by:

```
    _.each(self.itemViews, function (view) {
        Utils.destroyView(view); // Utility function that destroys the views.
    });
```

The issue I'm facing is that each time I instantiate a new parent view, rather than creating a new array for `itemViews`, backbone simply appends to one overall array called itemViews, as if each of the two parent views shares the same `itemViews` array. So rather than just destroying the appropriate tab's views, it destroys the views from both tabs. Is there either:

- A better way to create the list of subviews so that each list is unique to that parent view?
- A better way than using this type of list to destroy the subViews of a parent view?

Thanks!

Comment: Some more code would help. How is `_createSubView` called? From where do you call `_.each` loop to destroy views? A jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake thanks! Added code to show `_createSubView` call. _.each is in a function that resets infinite scroll because the items in the subviews are modified using a filter, so I need to reset the items in the view when they're modified. Let me know if you need more and I'll paste the jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your `itemViews` property so it is belongs to a view ***instance***.

You should do this in your `initialize` function as follows:

```
initialize: function(options) {

    this.itemViews = [];

    // rest of initialize code

}
```

That should make the itemVews behave the way you would expect.